# The sum of $49$ different positive integers is $2016$ . What is the minimum number of these integers which are odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of $49$ different positive integers is $2016$. What is the minimum number of these integers which are odd?
If we start from $0$ odd numbers we can consider the equation to be $2(n_1+n_2+n_3+\cdots+n_{49})=2016$. The minimum values of this expression is $>2016$, hence no possible solution for $0$ odd numbers. Similarly, we can continue taking number of odd numbers $=1,2,3,4...$ and get the answer which is 6 but isn't there a shorter method?

Comment: Hmm I think 2 can be a possible answer

Comment: @lalittolani That’s not possible. The sum of $47$ different even numbers is at least $$2(1+2+\cdots +47)=47\cdot 48 >2016$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that even + odd = odd, hence we can have only an even number of odd numbers.

The minimum sum that can be made out of the 49 positive numbers, with $2k$ odd numbers and $(49-2k)$ even numbers is given by
$$S = (49-2k)(50-2k) + 4k^2$$
We then need to solve the inequality
$$S \le 2016$$
Solving this gives us
$$8k^2 - 198k + 434 \le 0$$
The solution set of this inequality is approximately $[2.43,22.32]$. Since $k$ can only assume integer values, the smallest value of $k$ is 3, hence the minimum number of odd numbers is 6. $\blacksquare$

Comment: how did you arrive at second step

Comment: since S is the lower bound, if we have to get a sum of 2016 with the numbers, we need the lower bound to be less than or equal to 2016.

Comment: thankyou for replying but I want to understand the step above it

Answer (score 1):

A brute force approach is not terribly difficult. You can quickly calculate that:

The smallest $45$ even numbers sum to $45\cdot 46=2070$

The smallest $44$ even numbers sum to $44\cdot 45=1980$

The smallest $43$ even numbers sum to $43\cdot 44=1892$

It is impossible to choose $45$ or more even numbers, as they sum to $>2016$. Although the smallest $44$ even numbers sum to less than $2016$, using $44$ even numbers would require using $49-44=5$ odd numbers, and since $2016-1980=36$ which is an even difference, there is no way to pick $5$ odd numbers that sum to an even number. Hence you are forced to select $43$ as the maximum number of even numbers in the sum, requiring that you then pick $49-43=6$ odd numbers that sum to $2016-1892=124$. This is easily done, e.g. $1+3+5+7+9+99$